# More bits versus less bits in programming

Tags: java, binary, integer, long-integer, bit

So I'm somewhat new to programming and I'm been curious about the many  data types in Java. So to start, I've been focusing mostly on the ones to do with numbers.

Specifically, I've been looking at `int`, `long`. I've noticed that longs can have a much larger range of values than integers. Because of this, I've just been wondering why we don't just use longs all the time, instead of using integers most often.

Comment: [An easy Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20data%20types%20memory%20size)  would answer this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, more bits take up more memory...  also some data types are faster for computers to do math on than others (eg: integer math is faster than floating point math)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's essentially it; there are several flavors of "integer" type a and several flavors of "decimal" (floating-point) type. It's hard for people just starting out in programming to believe it, with hardware being so cheap, but there was a time that the difference between these types was the difference between fitting in the computer's memory or not. Nowadays the only time you still have those sorts of constraints would be enterprise-level systems or something that's still trying like an embedded system or minimal computer (though even the Raspberry Pi is outgrowing this classification).

Still, is good practice to limit yourself to the smallest reasonable variant of the data type your using. Memory is still an issue at the scale of, say, an older mobile device, or one running lots of apps. `long` is super-crazy-long for most common contexts, and the extra room is just wasted resources if you're not going to be dealing with numbers at that scale.